# htaccess mod rewrite preventing variables from assuming their values on included files

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I recently added a mod rewrite rule to my htaccess file to handle parsing category pages. After receiving assistance on this site the htaccess works fine. However, after I implemented the new htaccess I noticed two different conflicts/problems occurring in my script.

**1]** I had to change all include() functions, script links, and image sources from paths to full urls for the script to function although I added `<base href="/" />` just below the `<head>`.

**2]** Variables on included files, either through `include();` or `eval('?>'.file_get_contents($topad).'<?php;');`, are no longer assuming their values pre-established on the page they are being called into.

**For Example:**

Prior to the rewrite rule being added to the htaccess file the below form worked just fine when included using `include()`... but after, though the form is being called to the page, the variables  `$level` and `$page_url` do not assume their values.

```
echo '<form action="'.$level.'core/login/login.php" method="POST">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="returnto" value="'.$page_url.'">';
        echo '<div class="login-form-wrap">';
            echo '<fieldset><legend>Member Login</legend>';
                echo '<p>';
                echo '<label>Email</label>';
                echo '<input name="email" class="col_12" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email..." />';
                echo '</p>';

                echo '<p>';
                echo '<label>Password</label>';
                echo '<input name="password" class="col_12" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password..." />';
                echo '</p>';

                echo '<p>';
                echo '<input name="submitit" type="submit" class="button radius text-center expand" value="Log In">';
                echo '</p>';
            echo '</fieldset>';

            # forgot links
            echo '<p class="center">';
                echo '<span class="get-pass forgot-link" title="">Forgot Password</span> | ';
                echo '<span class="go-home forgot-link" title="">Go to Home Page</span>';
            echo '</p>';
        echo '</div>';      
    echo '</form>';
```

If I place the form on the file it works just fine.

**However...**

It should be noted that the file the form is being placed on is, in and of itself, a file being called through an `include();` function and though the file is called through `include();`, everything works just fine.

I have no idea how to resolve this issue... your assistance is much appreciated.

**Working htaccess:**

```
# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# http -> https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} s8w\.org [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# skip files and directories from rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ category.php?title=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?title=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: `https://www.s8w.org/category/restoration`

Comment: The line you see just below the banner that slides in is a header image which is represented as a variable on an included file

Comment: that is not the header... that is the top banner sliding in... the header image is a guy sitting on a doc with the word restoration on it

Comment: But `https://www.s8w.org/category.php?title=restoration` shows exact same page which doesn't get affected by any of the htaccess rules.

Comment: I place the included file on the page which renders as desired so you can see... the header being called changes dynamically for other category pages, each with specific variables

Comment: `include` is server side directive that is all handled by php without causing any rewrite rule. So e.g. `mod_rewrite` is invoked first then php module is loaded where `$level` value is set in the php code.

Comment: The bell rang in my head... the fact that `https://www.s8w.org/category.php?title=restoration` shows the same page is evidence it is not a htacces issue... do you have any idea as to what may be the cause?

Comment: It's been a while since I worked on PHP but check this Q&A https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675932/passing-a-variable-from-one-php-include-file-to-another-global-vs-not/4676007

Comment: Thank you for your assistance... you have eliminated a major concern in my mind with your explanations concerning htaccess... I'll take a look at the php side of things